# Associativity of operation of finite set

Tags: abstract-algebra, associativity

I'm studying Basic Algebra 1 by nathan jacobson at home.
[image: chap1.2 exercise 15]

I found that (i) implies for every element in G there exist right inverse and left inverse. I think I should show is associativity of multiplication by using (ii). I tried to find solution at google. But I couldnt find. Can you give me some hints or soultion? And where can I get solution for the book? Thank you.

Comment: Could you give the explicit construction of the multiplication table mentioned in the question? This might matter for the answer.

Comment: I think, for each ordered pair (x,y) where x,y are in G, x appears once in each row. Let one x is in i th row. In the i th row there is one unit, let the unit is j th column. Then in jth column, there is one y.  make rectangle on table whose vertexes are those. The other vertex must be the same for all rectangle. This is what I comprehend.

Comment: A different exercise: An associative binary operation on a set $G$ is a group iff for every $a,c\in G$ there exist unique $b,b'$ such that $ab=b'a=c.$

Answer (score 1):

I think it should suffice to say that in the rectangle we have $ac = 1, bc = x, ad = y$. Now for the fourth vertex to only depend on the pair $(x,y)$ we must have some $f(x,y)$ so that $\forall (x,y), a,b,c,d$ where $bc = x, ad = y$ we have that $bd = f(x,y)$. So to define $f$ just select some $a,b,c,d$ satisfying the above condition, now $(ii)$ implies that $f$ is independent of our choice. In which case take $1x = x, y1 = y$ so $(bc)y = xy = bd$ Now note that $d = a^{-1} y = cy$ so that $bd = b(cy)$ and we have that $(bc)y = c(by)$. This holds true for all $bc = x$. So for any pair of elements $b,c$, looking at $f(bc,y)$ shows that $bc$ associates with all other elements $y$. Since we can do that for all elements the monoid is associative.

This is probably a bit more complicated than it needs to be? The other direction can be gotten in the same exact way, association implies that we can always select $f(x,y)$ without having to make a choice by taking $a',b',c',d'$ and showing that association implies $bd = b'd'$.

Comment: I think there is very small problem that x and y are interchanged, but not important. Thanks for your answer.